# Installing VS 2015 missing project templates

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I do not understand why I cannot install Visual Studio 2015 correctly. I installed and it was fine and I created a new web mvc project and then I decided to install .NET Core 1.01 as I thought I had to now my project templates list has disappeared. I only have Windows and Silverlight as you can see from the screen shot below. I tried repair option however had no effect. What should I do? Uninstall and start again? I also Unticked Microsoft Web Developer tools and Updated however that had no effect i.e. after re-opening VS no templates and after reopening the install by clicking Modify from Add/Remove programs the check-box is still ticked so there is something wrong with the installation or perhaps my registry is screwed some how. I know other help I have here or on the internet give options to try however nothing seems to work. Any how can you please give me your thoughts options to try.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create .net core application you need to install the project template

here is the way to get it

```
https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015
```

download and install  `.NET Core 1.0.1 tools Preview 2`

Comment: Apologise ... tools Preview 2 is implied and this is what has caused the problem. Well at least I am guessing what caused it. Perhaps not however I have done this and it has made no difference. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: i install it without any issue

Comment: So should I uninstall everything and start again do you think?

Comment: yes and follow the that link and download update 3 from that :)

Comment: @Glen  whats happen ?

Comment: Yes I had to uninstall the 2015 C++ redistributables and Visual Studio Community and then reinstalling was fine. I don't really know what happen and I cannot remember now why I had to install the .NET core 1.0.1 tools separately. I played around with Updates and Repair options to no avail only uninstall and reinstall worked. Like I have all day or should I say 3 days until I force myself to uninstall first.